# Firefox Geckodriver Issue - INTERNALERROR>....WebDriverException: Message: TypeError: browsingContext.currentWindowGlobal is null

Tags: selenium, pytest, selenium-firefoxdriver

My suite works well with Chrome and Edge, but does not work with firefox. It start and abruptly ends.

Tried diff versions of geckodriver (32/64), updated firefox browser - no luck

Logs:
[Image with logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJlHQ.png)

Comment: I'm guessing it's lost track of a window handle... possibly a closed one.  Are you switching tabs/windows/frames in your code?  If so include in your post.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using `driver.switch_to.frame(...)` instead of `driver.switch_to_frame(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same exception, and only after reading this question and the comment I remembered that I had switched to an iframe (using `driver.switchTo().frame(...);` in Java). After switching back to the parent frame with `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();`, the exception went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while using geckodriver yet everything worked fine while using chromedriver.

I needed to use `driver.switch_to.default_content()` after switching to an iframe beforehand. I guess chromedriver doesn't have a problem if you don't specify it, but geckodriver does.