# Hi! someone knows about waits in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

Hi:  I'm trying to make a function with explicit wait. It works but in the end I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: 
Message: TypeError: browsingContext.currentWindowGlobal is null

Stacktrace:
getMarionetteCommandsActorProxy/get/<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/actors/MarionetteCommandsParent.sys.mjs:325:29
```

Please if anyone knows about this, I would be very grateful

I try this:

```
def esperar_elemento(self, XPATH, MyTextElement=None):  
        try:
            wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver,20)
            wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, XPATH))).click()
            print("El elemento a esperar es:", XPATH)
    
        finally:
           self.driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Previously to shown here code you probably switched inside an iframe but did not switch back to the default content.
This normally causes the error you mentioned.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68582694/firefox-geckodriver-issue-internalerror-webdriverexception-message-typee) more about this error and ways to fix that problem.

Comment: but I'm lost, I thought marionette was used within firefox, why the error says chrome?

Comment: @MoisésBriseñoEstrello how exactly this related to may answer here? Anyway, in case you have some question - please ask it as a new, separate question

Comment: You are right, at most, my comment should go on the question. And what would be the correct procedure, to erase my comment or just like this clarification here?